# Can't open User model using mongo db

Tags: python, django, mongodb, djongo

I'm using mongo db in my django project.
Whenever I try to open a record of User model in django admin, it gives me this error
[image]

All the other models are working fine. But getting problem in User model

and my user model is
[image]

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB doesn't contain the None type. Instead of None fill with null value or use pymongo.
This link may resolve your problem [Writing null value to MongoDB](https://community.dataiku.com/t5/Using-Dataiku/Writing-null-value-to-MongoDB/td-p/7435)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).